# Improper Table structure after Binding DataSource to DataGrid in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using .NET Studio 2003 and Framework 1.1
After Binding a DataSource to any DataGrid when I see the generated Source in browser.
it shows like this

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>Abc</td>
   <td>Def</td>
   <td>Ghi</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Abc</td>
   <td>Def</td>
   <td>Ghi</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

but instead of getting this I want to generate code like this (below)

```
<table>
 <thead> 
  <tr>
   <td>Abc</td>
   <td>Def</td>
   <td>Ghi</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Abc</td>
   <td>Def</td>
   <td>Ghi</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET 2.0 - DataGrid with tbody / thead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562010/asp-net-2-0-datagrid-with-tbody-thead)

Comment: @James Wiseman : ya but its not creating tbody. I want to create tbody too. and my table size can be more than 2000. So if I try to add each row one by one into tbody just like thead its taking too much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting pure html structure repeater is the best choice. you can use repeater as below for your code.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptData">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Abc
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Def
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Ghi
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Abc
            </td>
            <td>
                Def
            </td>
            <td>
                Ghi
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Hope this will hepls you...happy coding...